# String not showing up in console for C

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert a number in to a binary string:

```
void num_to_binary(const int num, char *binary) {
  int number = num;
  for(int i = 0; number > 0; i++){
   binary[i] = number % 2;
   number = number/ 2;
  }
  int length = strlen(binary);
  binary[length] = '\0';
  printf("%s", binary);
 }
```

While I'm sure that the binary string contains what I want (I tested the code by using
`printf("printed %d end",binary[i]);` in the for loop), I was unable to print it out by writing the code `printf("%s", binary);`
Any suggestions would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: `int length = strlen(binary);` fails unless `binary` was zeroed out before the `num_to_binary()` call.

Comment: CSnewbie, if `num == 0`, what should get printed?

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica if num == 0, a 0 should be printed.

Comment: Should 6 print `"110"` or `"011"`?  What about negative values?

Comment: I believe that we don't need to consider about neg values fro this assignment, and 6 should print 011  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do `binary[i] = !!(number % 2) + '0';`, otherwise strlen() will find the null character (value zero) somewhere it shouldn't, it is probably the first character in your case. See the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void num_to_binary(const int num, char *binary) {
    int number = num;
    for(int i = 0; number > 0; i++){
        binary[i] = !!(number % 2) + '0';
        number = number/ 2;
    }
    int length = strlen(binary);
    binary[length] = '\0';
    printf("%s", binary);
}

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[100];

    num_to_binary(25, buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `binary[i] = !!(number % 2) + '0'` would handle cases when `number < 0`.

Comment: I'm not sure why but the system gave me a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: It is likely because you didn't give the function a buffer large enough to accomodate the string.

Comment: Calling `strlen()` before storing the final `'\0'` does not work, if you don't have a `'\0'` at the very same location.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're setting the values of a character string to either 1 or 0.  When that string gets printed, those numbers are interpreted by the [ASCII table](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp).  Both 1 and 0 represent unprintable characters.  In fact, 0 is called a "null terminator" which will cause C to stop printing when it sees that value.

Instead, you want the ASCII representations of "1" and "0", which are 31 and 30, respectively.  So, you could replace that line with

```
binary[i] = 30 + number % 2;
```

EDIT:

It should be `30 + !!(number % 2)`.  That will take care of the situation when `number` is negative.

Answer (score 0):

`binary[i] = number % 2;` in this line, you're just storing a integer value to a string. And every time the value is either 0 or 1. So, `printf("%s", binary);` shows the charactera corresponding to ASCII 0 or 1.
The ASCII value for character '0' is 48 and '1' is 49. You have two ways:

1. binary[i] = number % 2 + 48; or,
2. binary[i] = number % 2 + '0';